# Call Asp.Net MVC Web API from Azure Web Scheduler Only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have a ASP.net MVC Web API hosted as App service in Azure which has some code that executes every hour with the help of an Azure Job Scheduler. I want to restrict this Web API only to be called by the Job Scheduler.

Is there any way to restrict it to be called from Job Scheduler only so no one from outside call it directly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest auth mechanism is to generate an API key that the client can send and have the server validate.